# Unknown provider: membershipServiceProvider <- membershipService <- membershipController error in angularjs Dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, modularity

I am able to run the code from one javascript file. but when I want to separate services into a separate file(in customServices folder) it is giving an injector error:- unknown provider. Debugger when placed in my membershipService.js - it is hit but still throws an error.

Similarly, I am unable to separate routing to another file. It is giving the same error.

folder structure:-

public 
  contollers
    1. app.js

customservices
    1. membershipService.js

views
  1. membershipdetails.html
  2. index.html

Index.html code:-

```
 <head>
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular- 
route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular- 
resource.js"></script>
<script src="CustomServices/membershipService.js"></script>
<script src="ngRoute/viewroute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="controllers/app.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>
<div>
<div class="container pt-5">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</div>
```

controller code - app.js

```
   var app = angular.module("tdmModule", ["ngRoute"]);
   app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
   $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
   }]);


 app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
 function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    templateUrl : "home",
    controller: 'homeController'
})
.when("/home", {
    templateUrl : "home",
    controller: 'homeController'
})
.when("/membershipdetails", {
    templateUrl : "membershipdetails",
    controller: 'membershipController'
})
.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);

   app.service("membershipService", function () {

   this.jsondata = function(getdata){
    var d = {};
    console.log("Service calling " +getdata);
    if(getdata != undefined && getdata.TopN != undefined){
            d.TopN = getdata.TopN;
    }
    if(getdata != undefined && getdata.MemberNo != undefined){
        d.MemberNo = getdata.MemberNo;
    }
   return d;
      };
    });


 app.controller('membershipController', function($scope,$filter, $http, 
 $httpParamSerializer, $location, membershipService, setnotanoption, 
 compileservice) {
 var absurl = $location.absUrl().split('/#!/')[1];
 $scope.pagename = absurl;

  app.controller('membershipController', function($scope,$filter, $http, 
  $httpParamSerializer, $location, membershipService, setnotanoption, 
  compileservice) {
var absurl = $location.absUrl().split('/#!/')[1];
$scope.pagename = absurl;
$scope.noOfColumn = false;





$http.get('http://localhost:3000/membership').then(function (res) {
    var options = res.data;
    $scope.options = options;



    $scope.removeField = function(rmdata) {
        setnotanoption.setNotAnOption(rmdata, false, options);
        var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector ("."+rmdata ) );
        myEl.attr('ng-show',false);

        compileservice.compile(myEl);

        var btnEl = angular.element( document.querySelector("#btnEl" ) );
        compileservice.compile(btnEl);
        setnotanoption.setNotAnOption(rmdata, false, options);
    };
    $scope.deleteField = function (index){
        $scope.rmdata.splice(index,1);
        alert("JSON Name is deleted");
      }

    $scope.addField = function(data) {
        if(data != undefined && data.optionSelect != null){
            var myEl = angular.element( 
    document.querySelector("."+data.optionSelect ) );
            myEl.attr('ng-show',true);
            compileservice.compile(myEl);
            setnotanoption.setNotAnOption(data.optionSelect, true, options);
        }
    };






         });
       });
```

NOTE:- IT Works till here. but once I move service code to different file as shown in beginning folder structure, it gives unknown provider error.

MY SERVICE CODE - WHERE I get error:-

```
 var app = angular.module("tdmModule", ["ngRoute"]);


    app.service("membershipService", function 
   ($location,$rootScope,$http,$filter,$cookies,$timeout,$document,$window) 
   {
this.jsondata = function(getdata){
    var d = {};
    console.log("Service calling " +getdata);

    if(getdata != undefined && getdata.TopN != undefined){
            d.TopN = getdata.TopN;
    }
    if(getdata != undefined && getdata.MemberNo != undefined){
        d.MemberNo = getdata.MemberNo;
    }

         if(getdata != undefined &&getdata.MemberStartDateHigh !=undefined){
        d.MemberStartDateHigh = getdata.MemberStartDateHigh;
    }

    return d;
};
 });
```

I have gone through 
1. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr
2. https://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/
3. [AngularJS Service not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090517/angularjs-service-not-working)
4. [Unknown Provider error using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638916/unknown-provider-error-using-angularjs)

I am missing some conceptual thing I guess. Some code intentionally removed for readability.

My concept of service injection is its a simple js file which can be injected in any controller in the application and used as per application. It needs to be registered with correct folder structure as well.

Comment: Had you also included the new file in your html document (via a <script> tag) _before_ angularjs bootstrap?

Comment: <script src="CustomServices/membershipService.js"></script> is included in index.html. I have included it after angular min js

Comment: Seems there is a syntax error on `getdata.MemberStartDateHigh! =undefined`. Maybe you mass up this when reducing the problem?

Comment: Syntax error corrected @tsh

Answer (score 0):

I added your code in a plunker to see what was going on.

First, you have lot of missing `}` and `)` in your example which makes your example uncompilable.

Then when I sorted that out it complained on the `setnotanoption` and `compileservice` which you have defined as a dependency in `membershipController`.
Those instances are not provided in your example.

When removing those, everything worked fine.

**Note**: Instead of binding all components on the object `app` I refered to the angular module as `angular.module("tdmModule")`

[Here's](https://plnkr.co/edit/pc7kTwNxkKGg4S6BBX2W?p=preview) the plunker.

Comment: I tried angular.module("tdmModule").service("membershipService" --- . It did not work as expected. Error: $injector:nomod
Module Unavailable
Module 'tdmModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] also occurred. Thanks for your response and concept anyways :)

Comment: @mank91 ok, instead of defining the var app = angular.module("tdmModule"... in your main file. use angular.module("tdmModule").config etc on the angular.module() all the way

Comment: Thanks sir for follow up. I tried the same in main file that is app.js. removed app variable and placed angular.module("tdmModule"). Still getting the same error.

Comment: @mank91 Could u change the order of the way you load the scripts where you define the angular.module("tdmModule", ["ngRoute"]) should be loaded before the dependent scripts

Comment: sorry to inform. it did not help.